# How to use INDEX, MATCH, SEARCH to return an exact match for the entire cell contents?

Tags: excel

I need a formula to assign tasks into general categories using a table of values. The purpose is so I can calculate how much a client would have spent last year using new per-task pricing (by category) instead of hourly rates (by task). The formula is super close, but it's returning first matches instead of exact matches to the entire cell contents. Several task types share text, so this is problematic.

I've tried messing with the EXACT function and using delimiters, but I'm not making real progress.

The formula I'm using now is:

=INDEX(" "&category&" ",MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&task&" "," "&D2&" ")),0))

What I'm looking for, for example, is to have the correct category populate out of Column P based on an exact, entire cell match between Column N and Column E.

In other words, when E exactly and entirely matches a value in N, return the corresponding value from P (located in the same row as N value).

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXYWi.jpg)

Comment: This isn't a regular VLOOKUP() task?  "exact, entire cell match between Column N and Column E." is a bit confusing, since it looks like you want to match using Col D ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood exactly what you want, but I think you can use, at E2:

=IF(COUNTIF(N:N,D2)>0;VLOOKUP(D2($N$2:$P$40,3,FALSE);0)

The formula is checking if the value at D2, mathces with some value at column N. If yes, it will return the correspondente alt column P. If not, will return 0